# Form of Dirac equation in curved spacetime and its derivation

Tags: dirac-equation, qft-in-curved-spacetime

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.2246) and [another](https://arxiv.org/abs/0710.0612), the Dirac equation for an uncharged fermion is written as $$i\gamma^{\mu}D_{\mu}\psi + \frac{m}{\hbar}\psi=0 $$

where $D_{\mu} = \partial_{\mu} + \Omega_{\mu}$, $\quad \Omega_{\mu} = \frac{1}{2}i\Gamma^{\alpha \ \ \beta}_{\ \mu}\Sigma_{\alpha\beta} $, $\quad \Sigma_{\alpha\beta} = \frac{1}{4}i[\gamma^{\alpha},\gamma^{\beta}] $. The $\gamma^{\mu}$ matrices satisfy $\{\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}\} = 2 g^{\mu\nu} $. Here $ g^{\mu\nu} $ is the inverse metric tensor with signature $(-,+,+,+)$.

a) How can one derive this equation?

b) I have seen the Dirac equation written with a minus sign before $m$. Why is the sign before $m$ plus here? Is it because of the metric signature? If so, how?

Comment: What is $\Gamma^{\alpha \ \ \beta}_{\ \mu}$ supposed to be? Shouldn’t it be a spin connection?

Comment: It is actually a spin connection, so you would better write it as $\omega_{\mu}^{a b}$ where $a, b$ are the coordinates in local reference frame, and $\mu$ in the global one. It is related in a some way to the Christoffel symbol $\Gamma$ but better denote it with different letters. The logic of derivation of the first equation is rather well explained here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/57568/.

Comment: The plus in front of the mass indeed comes from using the mostly plus Minkowski metric.